# Different Method to Set a Button's `OnClickListener` in Android

Tags: android, button, onclicklistener

Is there a different way to set a button's `OnClickListener` besides the following method, such as through XML?

```
final Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_id);

button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    public void onClick(View v) {
        // Handle click event.
    }

});
```

Comment: what does "part by part" mean?

Comment: I just want to know is it possible to write this code in any other way?

Comment: Why are you trying to write it another way? What is your goal? What is wrong with how it is written now?

Comment: The question helped me. I don't think it's too localized.

Comment: Five Ways to Wire Up an Event Listener: http://androidcookbook.com/Recipe.seam?recipeId=2359

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**1)** You have to implement `OnClickListener` in this option, and then implement its abstract method `onClick(View)`.

```
class YourClass implements OnClickListener {
   @Override
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);     
    setContentView(R.layout.your_activity);
    final Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_id);
    button.setOnClickListener(this);
   }

   public void onClick(View v) {
            //do something
   }
}
```

**2)**  Another option, you can also specify the method that your Button will launch from your layout.xml file. You just have to do something like this:

your_layout.xml

```
<Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:onClick="myCustomMethod" />
```

And back to your acitivity class, you just implement that method

```
class YourClass{ 
   ....


  public void myCustomMethod(View v){
    // do something
  }
}
```

Comment: juanmiguel@ thats it what i wanted. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

```
public void clickEvent(View v)
{
    switch(v.getID())
    {
        case R.id.ur_controlId:
            //do something...
            break;
    }
}
```

Declare `onclick` attribute in xml and provide the value as **clickEvent**.

Comment: Android28@ thank you. You are also ok